# Redirecting dependency logs to different appenders based on call initiator

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, jdbctemplate

I'm using Log4j2 for logging JdbcTemplate SQL and values:

```
    <Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="GlobalFileAppender"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="GlobalFileAppender"/>
    </Logger>
```

This produce nice logs. But since I'm using JdbcTemplate with many different DataSources (Sybase and Oracle), I would like to funnel these logs to different files based on location from where the calls are made.

For example, I have two DAO implementations

```
foo.bar.Dao1Impl
foo.bar.Dao2Impl
```

And every JdbcTemplate call from Dao1Impl I want to log to file1.log and calls from Dao2Impl to file2.log.

The problem is, specified loggers log to the same file independently from where the JdbcTemplate is called.

Comment: Create loggers for those classes instead of jdbcTemplate?